# Conversion looses qualifier

Tags: c++11

ALL,

Could someone please explain why following:

```
class Document
{
public:
    std::vector &GetVector() const { return m_myStringVector; };
private:
    std::vector<std::wstrng> m_myStrngVector;
};
```

gives:

```
 error C2440: 'return': cannot convert from 'const std::vector<std::wstring,std::allocator<_Ty>>' to 'std::vector<std::wstring,std::allocator<_Ty>> &'
          with
          [
              _Ty=std::wstring
          ]
note: Conversion loses qualifiers
```

It is a simple getter and don't need to be declared as const.

What am I missing?

Comment: You declared the getter as `const`, so it cannot return a non-`const` reference to the object's members.

Comment: @user17732522, no I didn't. I indicated that this is a getter and therefore will not change the object (I put the `const` after function definition, not before). `const std::vector&GetVector()` vs `std:::vector GetVector() const`. What am I missing?

Comment: @user17732522, I'm sorry I think I need some rest. I'm returning a reference not an object and therefore "changing the object of the class." Feels really stupid now.

Comment: I guess you got it now yourself, but as a guideline, if the getter returns a reference or pointer to a member, then either both the return value and the getter function itself should be marked `const` or neither should. Another trick (since C++14) is to just use `auto&` as return type. The compiler will then deduce the correct type and `const`-qualification for you automatically to match the function's `const`.